# Phantom 4 RTK Mobile SDK issues

Tags: dji-sdk

Phantom4RTK Mobile-SDK does not support Waypoint Missions.

Our Inspection software has been succesfully using the Matrice 210RTK / Mobile-SDK as a hardware platform. 
We have now purchased a newer P4RTK and have been trying to run our existing Android Mobile-SDK app.
Does not work.

The Mobile-SDK waypoint mission manager, which works on the Matrice 210RTK returns a very helpful DJI error when running the same code on the P4RTK. The helpful DJI error message is "The execution cannot be executed"

Despite paid premium DJI support tickets, not answer on this.

I'm coming to the conclusion that the Phantom 4 RTK is not fully supported in Mobile-SDK.

This is certainly a limitation the the new Phantom 4 RTK as as we would like to offer this product in addition to the Matrice 210RTK, which is no longer being produced. The newer Matrice 210RTK V2 now uses the same RTK ground station as the Phantom 4 RTK, we're now worried that the Matrice 210 RTK V2 has the same waypoint SDK issues as the Phantom 4 RTK.

This means our company cannot now recommend these DJI RTK products until the problems have been resolved or at least an answer from DJI premium support.

Is this a known issue ??

Comment: Same here, sooo annoying that we now pay premium support but still get the same bad experience as before, product wise and support wise! They don't seem to care at all...